# Porque no aparece diagrama Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, diagrama-er

buenas quisiera me ayudaran:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No aparece la opcion para crear el diagrama relacional.

Comment: si consigue la solucion por favor publicarla tengo el mismo problema, si yo logro solucionarlo tambien la publico

Comment: Por favor comparte la versión de Management Studio (la que aparece en el menu `Ayuda` -> `Acerca De` o `Help` -> `About`) y la versión de la instancia de SQL Server (la que resulta de `SELECT @@VERSION`).

Comment: version de sql por favor ayuda o mas pronto posible @luis cazares
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wrs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wrs.png) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pmfI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pmfI.png)

Comment: Ya puedes actualizar manteniendo los diagramas de bases de datos.

Comment: Veo que quitaste la marca de respuesta aceptada. ¿Hay algún problema que siga existiendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto puede resolver al menos el problema de uno de los dos. En la versión 18 de Management Studio fueron removidos los diagramas de base de datos. ([Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-and-removed-features-in-180-ga))

Una solución puede ser instalar una versión anterior como la 17.9 que se puede conseguir [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-ssms-releases).

**Actualización**

Los diagramas de base de datos regresaron en la versión 18.1 de SSMS a petición de la gente. Se puede descargar [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hola amigo, efectivamente eso fue lo que hice instalar una version anterior 17.x para poder visualizar el diagrama. Gracias

Comment: Si crees que la respuesta es adecuada, sería bueno que la marcaras como respuesta aceptada.